# Android Studio cant open Android Device Monitor

Tags: android-studio

When I try to open Android Device Monitor, The Android studio give an error:

For content of log file : http://codepaste.net/b9an16

[For image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0teGZ.png)

I'm using Android Studio(Beta) 0.8.2  - JRE 1.8.0_05-b13 amd64

How can fix do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was recently getting this same error. It turned out to be that my [.android folder was read only](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=92975). The solution that worked for me was to uninstall Android Studio, then re-install by running as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Run Android Studio as Administrator, no need to reinstall.